# How To Grab Data From Protected Local Storage (Blazor Server)

Tags: c#, blazor, backend, blazor-server-side

How do I grab stored data from the ProtectedLocalStorage ? When I attempt to do so I get blank values for the retrieved value (no crashes or error messages) and am able to concatenate the blank string with another string and display it (using login.razor as my test page). How do I grab the value without it being blank?

```
_Imports.razor

@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using MongoDB.Bson;
@using MongoDB.Driver;
@using Project
@using Project.Shared
@using Project.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
```

```
login.razor

@page "/login"
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage storage


<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>login</title>

    
</head>
  <body>
      <button @onclick = "@StoreValueAsync">set session data</button>

      <button @onclick = "@removeValueAsync">remove session data</button>

      <button @onclick = "@getValueAsync">get values</button>

      @testString

      
  </body>

@code
{
    private string? testString = "teststring";

    public void StoreValueAsync()
    {
        storage.SetAsync("username", "user");
        storage.SetAsync("password", "pass");
    }

    public void removeValueAsync()
    {
        storage.DeleteAsync("username");
        storage.DeleteAsync("password");
    }

    public void getValueAsync()
    {
        string? user = storage.GetAsync<string>("username").ToString();
        var pass = storage.GetAsync<string>("password");

        if (user != null)
        {
            testString = user + " and user is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            testString = user + "and user is null";
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This is a complete copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632049/in-blazor-server-net7-how-do-you-grab-data-from-protectedlocalstorage) post from a few days prior (March 3, 2023). Word for word, even the code blocks and formatting

Answer (score 3):

You can use various libraries to provide Local Storage, but it's pretty simple to do yourself, so here's a simple one page demo of how it's done.  Note that it depends on whether you're using Server or Web Assembly as to how you retrieve any values automatically on page load.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IJSRuntime js
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value=model.Value />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.SetAsync>Set</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick=this.GetAsync>Get</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.RemoveAsync>Remove</button>
</div>
@code {
    private string json = string.Empty;
    private MyData model = new();

    // Use this method if WASM
    //protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     //   => await TryGetAsync();

    private async Task SetAsync()
    {
        json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyData>(model);
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "mydata", json);
    }

    private async Task GetAsync()
    {
        if (!await TryGetAsync())
            model = new();
    }

    private async Task<bool> TryGetAsync()
    {
        bool hasProperty = await this.HasPropertyAsync();
        if (hasProperty)
        {
            json = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "mydata");
            model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(json) ?? new();
        }
        return hasProperty;
    }

    private async Task<bool> HasPropertyAsync()
        => await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("localStorage.hasOwnProperty", "mydata");

    private async Task RemoveAsync()
    {
        if (await this.HasPropertyAsync())
            await js.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.removeItem", "mydata");
    }

     // Use this method if Server
    //protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    //{
    //    if (firstRender && await TryGetAsync())
    //        StateHasChanged();
    //}

    public class MyData
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `await` all those async calls otherwise they become "fire and forget" and you won't capture the result.

I have removed all mention of username and password to discourage it

```cs
@code
{
    private string? testString = "teststring";

    async Task StoreValueAsync()
    {
        await storage.SetAsync("data1", "data1");
    }

    async Task removeValueAsync()
    {
        await storage.DeleteAsync("data1");
    }

    async Task getValueAsync()
    {
        string? data1 = await storage.GetAsync<string>("data1");

        if (data1 != null)
        {
            testString = data1 + " and data1 is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            testString = "data1 is null";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `storage.GetAsync<string>` function does not return the value as a string. It returns a `ValueTask<ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string>>`, so first of all you should await it. In the result of that, you can find the `Success` boolean and the `Value` property. That `Value` property contains the actual string value if `Success` is true.
So to retrieve the "username" value, the `GetValueAsync` function should be like this:

```cs
public async Task GetValueAsync()
{
    var result = await storage.GetAsync<string>("username");
    if (result.Success)
    {
        // Value exists in localStorage
        testString = "Username: " + result.Value;
    }else
    {
        // Value did not exist in localStorage
        testString = "Username is not found in the localStorage";
    }
}
```