# How to navigate in blazor to a page without creating new instance

Tags: navigation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to navigate to a razor page in my Blazor Server App but the NavigationManager.NavigateTo() seems like its creating an instance of the page everytime I try to navigate. how can i navigate to the same page created before

I tried the other parameters of the NavigateTo() method like ForceLoad and .. but the ctor of the destination page called every time it navigated.

Comment: Blazor Server creates a circuit for each tab in the browser. If you close a tab circuit might get deleted. I think there is no easy way to reconnect to such circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Components [pages are components] are managed by the Renderer.  You can't enter or re-enter a page.

Do you really want to reopen a page in the same state that you left it?

In which case, you separate out state data from the UI render logic and then save it to [and recover it from] an appropriate store.

This answer shows how to use Local Storage as the store.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75634537/13065781